# Multiple adjectives before uncountable noun

Tags: uncountable-nouns

If I say

> Sick, leave and benefit entitlement information is available here

Should I use is or are here in this sentence?

Comment: I would place a comma seperating"leave" and "benefit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Information *is*."

The only situation requiring "are", would be if the subject were plural. But the subject is "information" (*not* "sick leave and benefit entitlement"), and the word "information" doesn't become plural just because it is about more than one topic.

Also, regarding the comma: if this about "sick leave", I think you should remove the comma because with the comma there, it sounds like the information is about 3 separate things: 1) "sick", 2) "leave", and 3) "benefit entitlement".

Comment: I really meant three separate things as sick entitlement is an HR term in my understanding. Please check this website https://employsure.com.au/blog/for-part-time-staff-what-is-their-sick-entitlement/

Comment: @ook There is no such thing, idiomatically, as *sick entitlement*. Unless you take it to be slang and interpret it as meaning *wickedly cool entitlement*. I read the sentence and immediately rephrased it in my head as ***Information*** about *sick leave* and *sick leave benefits* ***is*** *available here*.

Comment: @JasonBassford I guess it is not intuitive but I have some more reference on this here https://schools.essex.gov.uk/staff/payroll/Documents/Checking%20staff%20sick%20entitlement%20held%20on%20payroll.pdf . The benefit entitlement is all about how much they can get reimbursed for their medical expense and other expenses but not about leave.

Comment: This is all specialized HR vocabulary and also only pertinent to the location in question. [.au ,. .uk , etc]